# Ubuntu 14.04. auth.log deleted

Tags: logging

the log file auth.log has dissappeared on my ubuntu 14.04 server.
Fail2ban log says that suddenly the file was gone:

```
2016-04-16 21:59:56,735 fail2ban.actions: WARNING [ssh] Ban 192.169.189.36
2016-04-17 01:27:51,182 fail2ban.filter : ERROR  Unable to get stat on /var/log/auth.log because of: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/log/auth.log'
2016-04-17 01:27:51,185 fail2ban.filter : ERROR  Unable to get stat on /var/log/auth.log because of: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/log/auth.log'
```

and fail2ban service finally went idle.

How can I recreate auth.log and mail.log and even more important does anybody have an idea how this could have happened? Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could recreate these files with following commands:

```
touch /var/log/auth.log && chmod 640 /var/log/auth.log && chown syslog:adm /var/log/auth.log
touch /var/log/mail.log && chmod 640 /var/log/mail.log && chown syslog:adm /var/log/mail.log
```

It's hard to say why the files got deleted. I have never experienced that. Maybe it could be the log-rotation if you have modified it recently.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. Both files are there again.

Comment: NP! I'm glad that I could help.

Answer (score 5):

For me, only the following worked:

`/etc/init.d/rsyslog restart`